# GIT: Unwanted files after a push

Tags: git, openshift

I'm using openshift, I have a remote git repository that look like this :

```
 .gitignore (contains "data/") 
 /source
 - test.php 
 /data
 - 1.png
 - 2.jpg
```

I checkout this repository on my computer. Then I change `test.php`. In same time, I deleted on the remote repository the files : `1.png` & `2.jpg` and I add the file `smile.jpg`.

remote:

```
 .gitignore (contains "data/") 
 /source
 - test.php 
 /data
 - smile.jpg
```

local

```
 .gitignore (contains "data/") 
 /source
 - test.php (changed)
 /data
 - 1.png
 - 2.jpg
```

Then when I : `git add` / `git commit` / `git push` the `test.php` modification from my computer.
My `smile.png` is replaced by the older files (`1.png` & `2.jpg`).

**What did I do wrong ?** I would like to keep my `smile.jpg` file.

PS: my remote repository is my production website and `data` contains all uploaded file. On each push, all my uploaded files are deleted :(

---

`git status` before `git commit`

```
$ git status
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   test.php
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `git status` before commit?

Comment: @eush77 yes, I put it in the question. Also, when I "browse master's files" I see this two files (1&2)

Comment: So… it's pretty clear that you commit only `test.php`. It seems that you are in the `/source` directory. You can try either `cd`ing out of `/source` or running `git add ..`.

Comment: @eush77 I use git gui, and I'm out of `/source` folder, In fact, my problem, is that I don't understand why `1.png` & `2.jpg` are "recreated" after I push modification on `test.php`. Also, `/data` should be ignore (as it is in .gitignore) -- i'm really new to git :(

Comment: You can try http://yuan3y.com/2014/10/setting-up-an-upload-folder-in-openshift/ && http://www.daangemist.nl/2014/12/29/configure-a-writable-upload-folder-on-openshift-for-a-php-cartridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Openshift, you have to use the openshift `~/app-root/data` folder.
The following question should help you to solve your problem 
[How to keep file sync'd in OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162209/how-to-keep-file-syncd-in-openshift)

Answer (score 1):

If you added the `data/*` folder to `.gitignore` after the files were already added to git, you'll have to

```
$ git rm data/1.png ; git rm data/2.png
```

Comment: Ok, I do instead: `git rm data -r`. But now, when a push change on `test.php`, `data` folder on remote repo is deleted ^^"

Comment: That is correct, if you don't have the `smile.jpg` being tracked; you can do this in your local machine

Comment: At the moment `smile.jpg` isn't created locally. I created it directly on the remote folder.

Comment: To be more clear, I don't understand why git delete my remote `data` folder as it should be ignored and should not tracked anymore while I commit / push.